# JSON Components to separate Data Frames in R

Tags: json, r

This is information parsed from resumes
I have a JSON file like,

```
object {2}
   data {1}
     resume{100}
       1{23}
         name: value
         work{3}
              title: value
              start date: value  
              end date: value
              2{20}
          ...
```

and so on,

I would like to create separate data frames or separate rows in the same data frame in R for all the resumes,

```
R Data Frame ,
Columns: name, work.title, work.start_date,work.end_date 

Row1: Information from 1st resume in JSON file

Row2: Information from 2nd resume in JSON file

Any help is highly appreciated.
```

Thank you,
Parth

```
As Jerome asked, here is sample of the json file
{"meta":{"status":200,"contentLocation":"http:\u002F\u002Fapi.indeed.com","sort":"date","q":"","v":"1","paging":{"current":"\u002Fresumes?client_id=5ae8db4a46efd1b2c207ae42746c0c8d8d93c43dd5bff7e4ae045004c0ab766e&useragent=DanLikesSeattle&v=1&l=19709&radius=40&sort=date&start=0&limit=100&pretty=0&rb=yoe%3A11-200","limit":100,"next":"\u002Fresumes?client_id=5ae8db4a46efd1b2c207ae42746c0c8d8d93c43dd5bff7e4ae045004c0ab766e&useragent=DanLikesSeattle&v=1&l=19709&radius=40&sort=date&start=100&limit=100&pretty=0&rb=yoe%3A11-200","start":0,"total":275879},"l":"19709","errors":{},"links":{"next":[{"href":"\u002Fresumes?client_id=5ae8db4a46efd1b2c207ae42746c0c8d8d93c43dd5bff7e4ae045004c0ab766e&useragent=DanLikesSeattle&v=1&l=19709&radius=40&sort=date&start=100&limit=100&pretty=0&rb=yoe%3A11-200","title":"Next Page"}],"up":[{"href":"\u002Fresumes","title":"Search Resumes"}]}},"data":{"resumes":[{"additionalInfo":"","awards":[],"certifications":[],"city":"Deptford, NJ","country":"US","dateCreated":{"displayDate":"February 9, 2015","granularity":"DAY","isoDate":"2015-02-09T06:00:00Z"},"dateModified":{"displayDate":"April 13, 2015","granularity":"DAY","isoDate":"2015-04-13T05:00:00Z"},"educations":[{"dateRange":{"displayDateRange":"2006 to 2007","endDate":{"displayDate":"2007","granularity":"YEAR","isoDate":"2007-01-01T06:00:00Z"},"startDate":{"displayDate":"2006","granularity":"YEAR","isoDate":"2006-01-01T06:00:00Z"}},"degree":"High School Diploma","field":"Technical","location":"Cape May Court House, NJ","school":"State of NJ"}],"firstName":"dummyfirstname","groups":[],"headline":"","lastName":"dummylastname","links":[],"location":{"admin1":"NJ","city":"Deptford","country":"US","formattedCity":"Deptford, NJ"},"militaryBackground":false,"militaryExperiences":[],"patents":[],"publications":[],"resumeKey":"6133565dfad7c519","skills":"Customer service, general labor\nWarehouse, delivery, salesman, \nInventory","summary":"","url":"\u002Fr\u002Fdummyfirstname-dummylastname\u002F6133565dfad7c519","workExperiences":[{"company":"Accu Staffing","dateRange":{"displayDateRange":"November 2013 to Present","startDate":{"displayDate":"November 2013","granularity":"MONTH","isoDate":"2013-11-01T05:00:00Z"}},"description":"Responsibilities\nWorked in two different warehouse mainly distribution of goods\n\nSkills Used\nCounting lifting sorting stacking labeling ","location":"Woodbury, NJ","title":"Warehouse Worker"},{"company":"wildwood linen","dateRange":{"displayDateRange":"May 2013 to December 2013","endDate":{"displayDate":"December 2013","granularity":"MONTH","isoDate":"2013-12-01T06:00:00Z"},"startDate":{"displayDate":"May 2013","granularity":"MONTH","isoDate":"2013-05-01T05:00:00Z"}},"description":"Responsibilities\nDelivered various goods to different companies in South Jersey area\n\nSkills Used\nCounting, inventory, customer service provider\nSalesman, ","location":"Wildwood, NJ","title":"Delivery Driver\u002FLaborer"},{"company":"earthtech","dateRange":{"displayDateRange":"September 2012 to February 2013","endDate":{"displayDate":"February 2013","granularity":"MONTH","isoDate":"2013-02-01T06:00:00Z"},"startDate":{"displayDate":"September 2012","granularity":"MONTH","isoDate":"2012-09-01T05:00:00Z"}},"description":"Responsibilities\nDelivered specific goods to different companies in the South Jersey area\n\nSkills Used\nInventory, customer service , mechanical skills,painting, welding tire repair","location":"Woodbine, NJ","title":"Delivery Driver\u002FWarehouse Worker"},{"company":"wildwood linen","dateRange":{"displayDateRange":"May 2007 to August 2012","endDate":{"displayDate":"August 2012","granularity":"MONTH","isoDate":"2012-08-01T05:00:00Z"},"startDate":{"displayDate":"May 2007","granularity":"MONTH","isoDate":"2007-05-01T05:00:00Z"}},"description":"Responsibilities\nDelivered different goods and services to various companies in the South Jersey area\n\nSkills Used\nCounting, inventory warehouse work, customer service provider, salesman","location":"Wildwood, NJ","title":"Deliver Driver"}]},{"additionalInfo":"","awards":[],"certifications":[],"city":"Newark, DE","country":"US","dateCreated":{"displayDate":"April 13, 2015","granularity":"DAY","isoDate":"2015-04-13T05:00:00Z"},"dateModified":{"displayDate":"April 13, 2015","granularity":"DAY","isoDate":"2015-04-13T05:00:00Z"},"educations":[{"dateRange":{"displayDateRange":"2014 to 2017","endDate":{"displayDate":"2017","granularity":"YEAR","isoDate":"2017-01-01T06:00:00Z"},"startDate":{"displayDate":"2014","granularity":"YEAR","isoDate":"2014-01-01T06:00:00Z"}},"degree":"Associates","field":"Paralegal Program","location":"Wilmington, DE","school":"Widener University"},{"dateRange":{"displayDateRange":"2008 to 2008","endDate":{"displayDate":"2008","granularity":"YEAR","isoDate":"2008-01-01T06:00:00Z"},"startDate":{"displayDate":"2008","granularity":"YEAR","isoDate":"2008-01-01T06:00:00Z"}},"degree":"Certificate Medical Billing & Coding","field":"Medical Billing & Coding","location":"Wilmington, DE","school":"Delaware Technical & Community College"},{"dateRange":{"displayDateRange":"2003 to 2008","endDate":{"displayDate":"2008","granularity":"YEAR","isoDate":"2008-01-01T06:00:00Z"},"startDate":{"displayDate":"2003","granularity":"YEAR","isoDate":"2003-01-01T06:00:00Z"}},"degree":"Associates","field":"Registered Nurse Program","location":"Wilmington, DE","school":"Delaware Technical Community College"}],"firstName":"dummyfirstname","groups":[],"headline":"Assignment as an Executive Administrative Assistant - Temporary Agencies","lastName":"dummyfirstname","links":[],"location":{"admin1":"DE","admin2":"003","city":"Newark","country":"US","formattedCity":"Newark, DE"},"militaryBackground":false,"militaryExperiences":[],"patents":[],"publications":[],"resumeKey":"86ae02b5d276fe1a","skills":"","summary":"","url":"\u002Fr\u002Fdummyfirstname-dummyfirstname\u002F86ae02b5d276fe1a","workExperiences":[{"company":"Swartz Campbell LLC","dateRange":{"displayDateRange":"2014 to 2015","endDate":{"displayDate":"2015","granularity":"YEAR","isoDate":"2015-01-01T06:00:00Z"},"startDate":{"displayDate":"2014","granularity":"YEAR","isoDate":"2014-01-01T06:00:00Z"}},"description":"Generated, printed and distributed bill drafts at month-end for assigned partners for their review\nâ€¢ Made adjustments and edits in accordance with the partners' requests including narrative edits and transfers of time and costs\nâ€¢ Processed approved write offs and prepared blended rate invoices when required\nâ€¢ Prepared electronic bills in LEDES (Legal Electronic Data Exchange Standard) format using E-Billing Program\nâ€¢ Submitted electronic bills to clients via their designated electronic billing systems; TyMetrix 360, Serengetti, Acuity, Counsel Link, Legal Exchange and several other sites\nâ€¢ Submitted timekeepers and rates for approval as needed\nâ€¢ Coordinated with colleagues and clients to resolve unsuccessful electronic bill submissions\nâ€¢ Tracked status of all submissions; including identify issues and addressing rejections accordingly\nâ€¢ Communicated within the firm, with clients, and with electronic billing service providers\nâ€¢ Performed other tasks as necessary for successful operation of electronic billing","location":"Wilmington, DE","title":"Legal Billing Assistant"},{"company":"Various Agencies","dateRange":{"displayDateRange":"2012 to 2015","endDate":{"displayDate":"2015","granularity":"YEAR","isoDate":"2015-01-01T06:00:00Z"},"startDate":{"displayDate":"2012","granularity":"YEAR","isoDate":"2012-01-01T06:00:00Z"}},"description":"â€¢\tAssignment as an Executive Administrative Assistant for a local Accounting Firm \nâ€¢\tAssignment as a Legal Assistant for a well-established law firm â€“ Just Legal, Inc.\nâ€¢\tAssignment as a Medical Secretary \u002F Scheduler for a well-established OB\u002FGYN doctorâ€™s office â€“ AppleOne Staffing\n","location":"","title":"Temporary Agencies"},{"company":"Doroshow, Pasquale, Krawitz & Bhaya","dateRange":{"displayDateRange":"2009 to 2012","endDate":{"displayDate":"2012","granularity":"YEAR","isoDate":"2012-01-01T06:00:00Z"},"startDate":{"displayDate":"2009","granularity":"YEAR","isoDate":"2009-01-01T06:00:00Z"}},"description":"â€¢Answered and transferred calls using a multi-line telephone system\nâ€¢ Scheduled appointments for the attorneys and clients using Outlook calendar system\nâ€¢ Scheduled hearings with the Industrial Accident Board\nâ€¢ Scheduled Depositions, Mediations, Arbitrations and other various scheduling needs with coordinating opposing counsel and doctor offices.\nâ€¢ Prepared litigation documents to coordinate with our group\nâ€¢ Data entry using the software Time Matters","location":"Bear, DE","title":"Legal Secretary"},{"company":"Matt's Auto Repairs","dateRange":{"displayDateRange":"2006 to 2009","endDate":{"displayDate":"2009","granularity":"YEAR","isoDate":"2009-01-01T06:00:00Z"},"startDate":{"displayDate":"2006","granularity":"YEAR","isoDate":"2006-01-01T06:00:00Z"}},"description":"â€¢\tAnswered and transferred calls using a multi-line telephone system\nâ€¢\tScheduled estimates and daily repairs\nâ€¢\tCreated estimates using Shop Keys and calling part warehouses for prices\nâ€¢\tCreated Excel spread sheets for Daily Revenue, and used the information to create reports for Bookkeeping purposes\nâ€¢\tBalanced the company checkbook and prepared weekly deposit\nâ€¢\tPrepared weekly payroll, payments for vendors, and parts warehouse \nâ€¢\tPrepared collection letters and followed through with collection calls\nâ€¢\tPrepared legal documents for DMV to take over ownership of vehicles\nâ€¢\tPicked up and sorted mail daily as well as order all office supplies\n","location":"New Castle, DE","title":"Administrative Assistant"}]}]}}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like json.

Comment: HI Jeroen, The file is JSON, I am using,https://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ to visualize it in this form

Comment: It would help if you provide an actual sample of your json data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jsonlite package does this automatically. For example:

```
library(jsonlite)
out <- fromJSON("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Rash2Svf")

# Extract resumes
resumes <- out$data$resumes
names(resumes)

# Work experiences for candidate 1 
print(resumes[[1, "workExperiences"]])

# Educations for candidate 2
print(resumes[[2, "educations"]])
```